# Добавление метода к объекту через прототип

Tags: javascript, prototype

Приведённый ниже код должен назначить объекту типа `Image` с помощью прототипа три новых метода: `protocol()`, `host()` и `pathname()`.
В браузере FireFox всё проходит нормально. Chrome выдаёт следующую ошибку:

> Uncaught TypeError: document.i1.protocol is not a function

Соответственно, и остальные функции `document.i1.host` и `document.i1.path` не выполняются.

В чём заключается проблема, и как её решить?

```
function pr() {
    a = this.src.split(':');
    return a[0] + ':';
}

function ho() {
    a = this.src.split(':');
    path = a[1].split('/');
    return path[2];
}

function pa() {
    path = this.src.split('/');
    path[0] = '';
    path[2] = '';
    return path.join('/').split('///').join('/');
}

Image.prototype.protocol = pr;
Image.prototype.host = ho;
Image.prototype.pathname = pa;

document.write("<IMG NAME=i1 SRC='img1.jpg'><BR>");
document.write(document.i1.src + "<BR>");
document.write(document.i1.protocol() + "<BR>");
document.write(document.i1.host() + "<BR>");
document.write(document.i1.pathname() + "<BR>");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Полученный `<img>` (например, с помощью `document.getElementById('img')` или `new Image()`) имеет тип `HTMLImageElement`. Соответственно, добавлять новые методы нужно именно в его прототип.

Пример:

```js
function log(info) {
    document.body.innerHTML += info + "<br/>";
}

HTMLImageElement.prototype.protocol = function() {
    log("Protocol is called");
};

var img = document.getElementById('img');
log("Got image: " + img.constructor.name);
img.protocol();

var newImage = new Image();
log("New image: " + newImage.constructor.name);
newImage.protocol();
```

```html
<img id='img' /><br/>
```

Comment: ну объяснение не совсем верное :-) иначе в firefox Тоже не работало бы, но решение правильное :-)

Comment: @Grundy а что не совсем верно? Да, в Firefox, например, `img.__proto__` выдаст `HTMLImageElementPrototype`, а не `HTMLImageElement`, но всё же тип таков, равно как и методы устанавливаются (один из вариантов на MDN) через `HTMLImageElement.prototype`.

Answer (score 1):

```js
  function pr() {
    a = this.src.split(':');
    return a[0] + ':';
  }

  function ho() {
    a = this.src.split(':');
    path = a[1].split('/');
    return path[2];
  }

  function pa() {
    path = this.src.split('/');
    path[0] = '';
    path[2] = '';
    return path.join('/').split('///').join('/');
  }

  Image.prototype.protocol = pr;
  Image.prototype.host = ho;
  Image.prototype.pathname = pa;

  var out = document.getElementById("out"), i1, html;

  out.innerHTML = "<IMG NAME=i1 id='i1' SRC='http://stabfrenzy.com/albums/kermit/kermit_.jpg'><BR>";
  i1 = document.getElementById('i1');

  html = out.innerHTML;
  html += "src: " + i1.src + "<BR>";
  html += "protocol: " + i1.protocol() + "<BR>";
  html += "host: " + i1.host() + "<BR>";
  html += "pathname: " + i1.pathname() + "<BR>";
  
  out.innerHTML = html;
```

```html
<div id="out"></div>
```

Вероятно, вы несколько раз выполнили скрипт на странице, и появилось несколько элементов с именем "i1", поэтому в последующи разы нужно было бы обращаться к `document.i1[0].protocol()`.

Лучше сделать так:

```
document.write("<IMG ID='i1' SRC='img1.jpg'><BR>");
var i1 = document.getElementById('i1');

document.write(i1.src+"<BR>");
document.write(i1.protocol()+"<BR>");
...
```

Comment: Написал как вы предложили и через innerhTML и через getElementById('i1');

Дебаг режим в Chrome выдает одну и ту же ошибку на строчку 
`html += "protocol: " + i1.protocol() + "<BR>";`


>Uncaught TypeError: i1.protocol is not a function

Comment: @NewSheriff, а без _write_ пробовали? так же как в примере?

Comment: @Grundy если повыбрасывать из кода автора всё не относящееся к вопросу, то получится [такой пример](http://jsfiddle.net/Regent3000/hpj95cmm/). В Firefox 42 работает, в Opera 33.0 - нет.

Comment: @Regent, в хроме тоже не работает. Все это из-за того что нужно другой прототип расширять :-)

Comment: @Regent Если не секрет, то какой?

Comment: @Regent извиняюсь нашел ваш ответ)

Answer (score 0):

Вот рабочий вариант. Спасибо [@Regent](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/183458/regent) и [@Sergiks](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/7161/sergiks) и [@Grundy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/186999/grundy)

```
<img NAME=i1 ID='img' SRC='img1.jpg' /><br/>

<script>
    function log(info) {
        document.body.innerHTML += info + "<br/>";
    }

    HTMLImageElement.prototype.protocol = function() {
        a = this.src.split(':');
        log(a[0]+':');
    };

    HTMLImageElement.prototype.host = function() {
        a = this.src.split(':');
        path = a[1].split('/');
        log(path[2]);
    };

    HTMLImageElement.prototype.path = function() {
        path = this.src.split('/');
        path[0]='';
        path[2]='';
        log(path.join('/').split('///').join('/'));
    };

    var img = document.getElementById('img');
    log("Got image: " + img.constructor.name);
    img.protocol();
    img.host();
    img.path();
</script>
```

При открытии страницы все работает корректно, выводиться вся необходимая информация, не зависимо от браузера.

> Got image: HTMLImageElement
>
> http:
>
> localhost
>
> /JavaScriptLearning/img1.jpg